# Getting Cannot resolve overloaded method even when the two functions have different function signatures in scala

Tags: scala, generics

I am trying to create a generic serializer in scala for my use case:

```
class X[V]() extends Codec[V] {
override def serialize(data :V): Array[Byte] = {

    val serialization     = TimedAction(SerializationUtils.serialize(data))
    val uncompressedBytes = serialization.resultUnsafe
    uncompressedBytes
  }
```

I am getting this error

*Cannot resolve overloaded method 'serialize'*

This clearly looks to me as some generics issue

```
public static byte[] serialize(final Serializable obj) {}

public static void serialize(final Serializable obj, final OutputStream outputStream) {}
```

This SerializationUtils belongs to **package org.apache.commons.lang3**

I have two questions

1. Why I am getting this error when clearly both function have different function defintion.
2. How do I resolve this error.

Is there a way to directly mention to call this specific function. FYI I want to call the function *serialize(final Serializable obj)*

Comment: `data` is not necessarily a `Serializable` because `V` can be any type, so neither of the overloads matches. A type constraint `[V <: Serializable]' might fix it.

Comment: @Tim Trying something like:
 `override def serialize(data :[V <: Serializable]): Array[Byte] `
is giving error

Or did you mean:
`class UserProfileDataCouchbaseCodec[V <: Serializable](metricsReporter: MetricsReporter) extends Codec[V] `

Comment: I mean `class X[V <: Serializable]()` (which I think is your second option) but not familiar with this library so might not be right (which is why this is a comment not an answer!)